# How to check the fragment activity info in current Activity?

Tags: android

I want to create a tool to collect current Activity detail information. Is there any API can get the fragment activity info in current Activity, please?

I notice the FragmentManger. But it needs the instance of Activity. I only can get ActivityInfo from some services.

Comment: What exact information is it that you would like to know/show?

Comment: are you looking to get info of Activities in your own app or other apps?

Comment: Hi Amith. I want to get info of Activities from other apps

Comment: Hi cYrixmorten, Activity class name, package name, fragment class name and so on. I use it to tracking usage of Activity class